# How to set CheckBox in CListCtrl to be unavailable?

Tags: mfc

`CListCtrl` sets the CheckBox property, how to make the CheckBox of a row unavailable (cannot: check or uncheck)?

Comment: `CListCtrl` does not set the CheckBox property. The default is even not to have checkboxes. It was you who have set it , by indicating the extended style `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` via resource editor or code.

Comment: And I think I found an interesting read for you: Creating a listview with checkboxes on some items but not others https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140113-00/?p=2103